# Flutter: How to prevent compilation of a file(s) in android studio

Tags: java, ios, flutter, android-studio

Here is the situation: I have a large project and I made breaking changes that affect many files but I want to test these changes on these files in small groups. Which means I want in each phase to run the project and compile only say for example 3 files to see how they are affected by these changes, and the rest of the files must not be compiled (the project runs normally with only these 3 files compiled for example). I tried commenting all the code in these unwanted files but this solution is not practical as there are too many of them, I am searching if there is a solution like giving a command line option to exclude these files without touching them or any other similar clean solution.

- note: I mentioned flutter just in case it may be relevant and I don't think I should provide any code for this question